# The required anti-forgery form field “__RequestVerificationToken” is not present Error on partial view post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csrf, partial-views, x-xsrf-token

I'm posting data from the partial view to perform update operation
using MVC `@Ajax.ActionLink` method, but while including the tag
`[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` it is giving me the error.

It is working fine when I remove the tag `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`
from action method. My view already had one Antiforgery token.  I
tried removing `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` from partial view but still
got the same error.

### _partialView.csHtml code :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.Hidden("hdnID", "", new { @id = "hdnID" })

    @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "Action", "Controller", new { ID = "Ids" },
         new AjaxOptions
         {
              HttpMethod = "POST",
              InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
              UpdateTargetId = "divLinkedUnlinkedVLans",
              LoadingElementId = "progress"
         }, new { @id = "btnRight", @class = "btn btn-default fa fa-caret-right fa-4x center" })
    }
```

### Controller Code :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Action(string ID)
{
   try
   {
     // Some database operation
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
      throw;
   }
}
```

### Partial View call from Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ActionName()
{       
     return PartialView("_partialView", Data object having data from database);
}
```

> When the button is clicked the form is posted back and it is giving
>   the error message as '__requestverificationtoken is not present'. Help
>   me with posting the antiforgery token to controller so as I can avoid
>   CSRF attacks.

Comment: @JonathonChase already gone through the link it says create form and put the @Html.AntiForgeryToken(). My code already have this and also the problem is for partial view.

Comment: You're using `Html.BeginForm`, while the duplicate suggests `@Ajax.BeginForm`. Have you tried changing to the Ajax form?

Comment: Thanks it solved my issue.